# Android Studio | Navigate to file in the project explorer from the editor

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, projects-and-solutions

I find myself with many files open in the editor (in separated tabs), and sometimes I want to find specific file in the project explorer.

Does there is any shortcut to reveal the file in the project window ?

**EDIT** to do the question more clear I add a picture:
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There isn't a single key combo that can do this, as far as I know, but you can go with

## On Windows

`Alt + F1` followed by either `1` or `enter`

## On Linux (using Gnome)

`Alt + Shift + 1` followed by either `1` or `enter`

## On Mac OS

`Option + F1` followed by either `1` or `enter`

Android Studio is based on intelliJ, which has a function to open the current file or symbol in various views. The default key combo (in Windows) is `ALT + F1`.

This offers to open the current file or symbol in a bunch of different views, but the first option (with shortcut key `1`) is the project view.

It's the same as choosing the `Navigate` > `Select in...` menu option, followed by option 1.

**Note that you can customise the key mappings, or select other defaults instead of the default intelliJ configuration, so this might not be the case with your set up.**

You can check the key mapping in `settings` > `Key map` and search for `Select In...` or, more simply, click the navigate menu and look at the `Select In...` option to see the shortcut key displayed in the drop down.

Comment: I search in the `Key map` you note here, it's really looks there is no option to do this.. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, of course. It's also handy to know that hitting F4 in a file or project list will open the currently highlighted file in the editor - this is especially handy from VCS change lists.

Answer (score 6):

You can go to `Navigate -> Select In`, which has default shortcut `Option+F1` on macOS.

For Xcode, the shortcut is `Cmd+Shift+J`. If you want the same, follow these steps

- Go to `Android Studio -> Preferences -> Keymap`
- Search for `Select In` in `Navigate`
- Right click and select `Add Keyboard Shortcut`
- Press `Cmd+Shift+J`

[image]